# How does the Tridion GUI Extensions CommandSet map to js methods?

Tags: tridion

How does the Tridion GUI Extension config map the names to the JS file?  For example, I am using Jaime's [HelloWorld post](http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com/2011/02/sdl-tridion-2011-ga-gui-extension-hello.html) with example files.  The most important part feels to be the CommandSet section.

```
<cfg:commandset id="HelloWorldCM.Interface">   
  <cfg:command name="HelloWorldCM" implementation="Extensions.HW"/>
  <cfg:dependencies>
    <cfg:dependency>HelloWorldCM.Commandset</cfg:dependency>
  </cfg:dependencies>
</cfg:commandset>
```

Can someone please help me understand the following attributes and how they map to the underlying .js file for the extension?

- name
- implementation
- cfg:dependency

I have tried changing these things in both config and js file but how they are mapped is a mystery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The three attributes you mention are really all pointers that tie the whole extension together. If you look higher up in the Jamie's sample, you will see this:

```
<ext:contextmenus>
  <ext:add>
    <ext:extension name="HelloWorldCMExtension" assignid="" insertbefore="cm_refresh">
      <ext:menudeclaration>
        <cmenu:ContextMenuItem id="ext_HelloWorldCM" name="Hello World!" command="HelloWorldCM"/>
      </ext:menudeclaration>                            
      <ext:dependencies>
        <cfg:dependency>HelloWorldCM.Example</cfg:dependency>
      </ext:dependencies>              
      <ext:apply>
        <ext:view name="DashboardView"/>
      </ext:apply>
    </ext:extension>
  </ext:add>          
</ext:contextmenus>
```

This XML adds a button to the CME's context menu.

`command="HelloWorldCM"` refers to the command with the matching `name` attribute in the `commandset`

`implementation="Extensions.HW"` in the command set actually refers to the namespace in the accompanying HellowWorldCM.js file

`cfg:dependency` points to the top of the config file at the `<cfg:group name="HelloWorldCM.Commandset" merger="Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Configuration.Resources.CommandGroupProcessor" merge="always">` node in order to know which CSS and JS to include.