# Tridion 2011 GUI Extension, how to include css file?

Tags: tridion

I've been building a JavaScript and CSS only GUI extension.

I followed the instructions in Albert's post here:
http://albertromkes.com/2012/01/30/tridion-gui-extensions-how-to-load-a-javascript-without-showing-a-gui-element/

The JavaScript loads in OK but I can't get the CSS included, am I missing something?

Here's an approximation of my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<Configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge"
      xmlns:cfg="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration"
      xmlns:ext="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions"
      xmlns:cmenu="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu">
  <resources cache="true">
    <cfg:filters/>
    <cfg:groups>
      <cfg:group name="Rob.Prototype.Extensions"
       merger="Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Configuration.Resources.CommandGroupProcessor" 
       merge="always">
        <cfg:domainmodel name="Rob.Prototype.Extensions.Domain">
          <cfg:fileset>
            <cfg:file type="script">/Scripts/script1.js</cfg:file>
            <cfg:file type="script">/Scripts/script2.js</cfg:file>
            <cfg:file type="style">/CSS/styles.css</cfg:file>
          </cfg:fileset>
          <cfg:services/>
        </cfg:domainmodel>
      </cfg:group>
    </cfg:groups>
  </resources>
  <definitionfiles/>
  <extensions>
    <ext:editorextensions/>
    <ext:dataextenders/>
  </extensions>
  <commands/>
  <contextmenus/>
  <localization/>
  <settings>
    <defaultpage>/Views/Default.aspx</defaultpage>
    <navigatorurl>/Views/Default.aspx</navigatorurl>
    <editurls/>
    <listdefinitions/>
    <itemicons/>
    <theme>
      <path>/CSS/</path>
    </theme>
    <customconfiguration/>
  </settings>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Hey Rob, I see that you accepted my answer. Does that mean that it was indeed a matter of putting your CSS in a separate (non-domainmodel) group? If that is the case, I'll update my answer to say that a bit more explicitly, since likely others will encounter this problem too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The domain model is supposed contain non-visual things only, so Tridion only processes non-visual file types. You should not include CSS files in a `domainmodel`, but instead put them in a separate `fileset` outside of any `domainmodel`.

This requires that you have a GUI element that uses the group that your CSS is in. If you weren't planning to add any GUI elements, you could add a dummy ribbon button to links to the CSS.

Comment: Puf, I'm not 100% sure to be honest. I was following the lead from the blog post, since my extension doesn't really extend a command or editor directly. I am looking for a particular element on a Tridion Page and firing some Javascript based on that. It may be that I can extend in another place.

Comment: I am 80% sure that CSS files will not be processed as part of a domainmodel element. You will want to set up a regular fileset with the CSS in it and then create a dependency from some UI extension to that group.

Comment: Could I create a dummy ribbon button to force the CSS in perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

This might help you

[How does the Tridion GUI Extensions CommandSet map to js methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393851/how-does-the-tridion-gui-extensions-commandset-map-to-js-methods)

The same should apply to CSS as for JS.

If that doesn't work, have you tried incrementing the modification attribute in System.config stored at C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the answer Rob but the following blog post from [@poeticGeek](https://twitter.com/poeticGeek) may help you out.

[Setting up a Tridion 2011 GUI extension in 8 steps](http://yoavniran.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/setting-up-a-tridion-gui-2011-extension-in-8-steps/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the config from an extension I wrote that 'injected' javascript into the publish dialog view, maybe worth giving it a shot to see if it also includes any css:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge" xmlns:cfg="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration" xmlns:ext="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions" xmlns:cmenu="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu">
  <resources cache="true">
    <cfg:extensiongroups>
      <cfg:extensiongroup name="Company.Extensions.Group">
        <cfg:extension target="Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Views.Popups.Publish">
          <cfg:insertafter>Company.Extensions.Resources</cfg:insertafter>
        </cfg:extension>
      </cfg:extensiongroup>
    </cfg:extensiongroups>
    <cfg:groups>
      <cfg:group name="Company.Extensions.Resources">
        <cfg:fileset>
          <cfg:file type="script">/js/SelectRollbackFailure.js</cfg:file>
          <cfg:file type="script">/js/NoPublishItemWarning.js</cfg:file>          
        </cfg:fileset>
      </cfg:group>
    </cfg:groups>
    </resources>
    <definitionfiles/>
  <extensions>
    <ext:dataextenders/>
    <ext:editorextensions />
  </extensions> 
    <commands />
    <contextmenus/>
  <localization></localization>
    <settings>
        <defaultpage />
        <navigatorurl />
        <editurls/>
        <listdefinitions/>
        <itemicons/>
    <theme>
      <path></path>
      <resourcegroup />
    </theme>     
    <resourceextensions>
      <resourceextension>Company.Extensions.Group</resourceextension>
    </resourceextensions>
    <customconfiguration></customconfiguration>
  </settings> 
</Configuration>
```

You'll need to change this part:

```
<cfg:extension target="Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Views.Popups.Publish">
```

To where you'd like the items to be included.  If it's not quite right, or you need an explanation let me know.

p.s I also suspect some empty nodes can be stripped out :)